# Nettle 3.4 returns an error with the make command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gmp, mars-simulator, nettle

I've been trying to run MARSS simulator on Ubuntu 18.04. So it threw an error saying gnuTLS library not found. When I went on installing that library it threw an error saying libnette 3.1 not found, so I go ahead and try to install nettle 3.4. This is the error I am encountering while installing nettle. Any help is appreciated.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-static && make



checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for -R flag... using -Wl,-rpath,
Searching for libraries
checking /usr/lib... added
checking /usr/local/lib... added
checking /sw/local/lib... not found
checking /sw/lib... not found
checking /usr/gnu/lib... not found
checking /opt/gnu/lib... not found
checking /sw/gnu/lib... not found
checking /usr/freeware/lib... not found
checking /usr/pkg/lib... not found
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for ifunc support... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking if LD -Wl,--version-script works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for nm... nm
checking for objdump... objdump
checking for ar... ar
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for build system executable suffix... 
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for uid_t in sys/types.h... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking size of long... 8
checking size of size_t... 8
checking openssl/evp.h usability... no
checking openssl/evp.h presence... no
checking for openssl/evp.h... no
checking valgrind/memcheck.h usability... no
checking valgrind/memcheck.h presence... no
checking for valgrind/memcheck.h... no
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking for working alloca.h... yes
checking for alloca... yes
checking malloc.h usability... yes
checking malloc.h presence... yes
checking for malloc.h... yes
checking for strerror... yes
checking for secure_getenv... yes
checking for getline... yes
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for __attribute__... yes
checking for stdint types... stdint.h (shortcircuit)
make use of stdint.h in nettle-stdint.h (assuming C99 compatible system)
checking for fcntl file locking... yes
checking for __gmpz_powm_sec in -lgmp... no
configure: WARNING: GNU MP not found, or too old. GMP-5.0 or later is needed, see http://gmplib.org/.
    Support for public key algorithms will be unavailable.
configure: Compiler uses 64-bit ABI. To change, set CC.
configure: Libraries to be installed in ${exec_prefix}/lib.
configure: Looking for assembler files in x86_64.
checking CCPIC... -fpic
checking if globals are prefixed by underscore... no
checking for ELF-style .type,%function pseudo-ops... yes
checking for ELF-style .type,#function pseudo-ops... no
checking for COFF-style .type directive... no
checking if we should use a .note.GNU-stack section... yes
checking if .align assembly directive is logarithmic... no
checking for m4... m4
checking for makeinfo... not-found
checking for library containing clock_gettime... none required
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.make
config.status: creating config.m4
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating version.h
config.status: creating tools/Makefile
config.status: creating testsuite/Makefile
config.status: creating examples/Makefile
config.status: creating nettle.pc
config.status: creating hogweed.pc
config.status: creating libnettle.map
config.status: creating libhogweed.map
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: linking x86_64/aes-encrypt-internal.asm to aes-encrypt-internal.asm
config.status: linking x86_64/aes-decrypt-internal.asm to aes-decrypt-internal.asm
config.status: linking x86_64/camellia-crypt-internal.asm to camellia-crypt-internal.asm
config.status: linking x86_64/md5-compress.asm to md5-compress.asm
config.status: linking x86_64/memxor.asm to memxor.asm
config.status: linking x86_64/memxor3.asm to memxor3.asm
config.status: linking x86_64/poly1305-internal.asm to poly1305-internal.asm
config.status: linking x86_64/chacha-core-internal.asm to chacha-core-internal.asm
config.status: linking x86_64/salsa20-crypt.asm to salsa20-crypt.asm
config.status: linking x86_64/salsa20-core-internal.asm to salsa20-core-internal.asm
config.status: linking x86_64/serpent-encrypt.asm to serpent-encrypt.asm
config.status: linking x86_64/serpent-decrypt.asm to serpent-decrypt.asm
config.status: linking x86_64/sha1-compress.asm to sha1-compress.asm
config.status: linking x86_64/sha256-compress.asm to sha256-compress.asm
config.status: linking x86_64/sha512-compress.asm to sha512-compress.asm
config.status: linking x86_64/sha3-permute.asm to sha3-permute.asm
config.status: linking x86_64/umac-nh.asm to umac-nh.asm
config.status: linking x86_64/umac-nh-n.asm to umac-nh-n.asm
config.status: linking x86_64/machine.m4 to machine.m4
config.status: linking x86_64/gcm-hash8.asm to gcm-hash8.asm
config.status: executing dummy-dep-files commands
config.status: executing nettle-stdint.h commands
config.status: creating nettle-stdint.h : __NETTLE_STDINT_H
config.status: nettle-stdint.h is unchanged
configure: summary of build options:

  Version:           nettle 3.4
  Host type:         x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  ABI:               64
  Assembly files:    x86_64
  Install prefix:    /usr
  Library directory: ${exec_prefix}/lib
  Compiler:          gcc
  Static libraries:  no
  Shared libraries:  yes
  Public key crypto: no
  Using mini-gmp:    no
  Documentation:     no

make all-here
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/vansh2795/nettle-3.4'
./config.status config.h
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
echo timestamp > stamp-h
m4 ./asm.m4 machine.m4 config.m4 aes-decrypt-internal.asm >aes-decrypt-internal.s
/bin/sh: 1: m4: not found
Makefile:379: recipe for target 'aes-decrypt-internal.o' failed
make[1]: *** [aes-decrypt-internal.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/vansh2795/nettle-3.4'
Makefile:49: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: It says "m4: not found", I am sure if you think a bit you can come up with a solution that involves your package manager and "m4"... Speaking of which, Ubuntu has a gnutls package.

Comment: Neither [`README`](https://git.lysator.liu.se/nettle/nettle/blob/master/README) nor [`INSTALL`](https://git.lysator.liu.se/nettle/nettle/blob/master/INSTALL) mention the prerequisite, but you need to install M4.